# How to identify the jQuery collapsable and append html to it

Tags: jquery

I have got two `data-role="collapsible"` elements of jQuery as shown in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/znz17ctm/16/

On click of the Collapsable `div` , I am capturing the event.

How can I identify the and append some sample `div` to it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my-collaspible').bind('expand', function() {
        var elemclciked = $(this).attr('data_attr');

        var uihtml = $('<div>Sample Div For Test</div>')
    });
    $('.my-collaspible').bind('collapse', function() {
        alert('Collapsed');
    });
});
```

This is the html of the data-collapsable

```
 <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" class="my-collaspible ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed" data_attr="Haii">
         <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed"><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inherit">Haii <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon  ui-link"></a><span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span></a></h3>
         <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true"></div>
      </div>
```

My question is can i remove all the contents of the class div data-role="collapsible" so that it looks exactly as

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" class="my-collaspible ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed" data_attr="Haii">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append do so:

```
$('.my-collaspible').bind('expand', function() {
    var elemclciked = $(this).attr('data_attr');

    var uihtml = $('<div>Sample Div For Test</div>')
    $(this).append(uihtml);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,please see my question (i edited just now ) , please let me know if that possible .

Comment: So that on click of the div , i will clear the contents and add the html based on the results from ajax .

Comment: you can clean before you append this way  `$(this).empty().append(uihtml);`